# Drupal Grouped Photo Gallery

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules, image-gallery

I'm new to Drupal (I'm using D7) and trying to understand how things are put together and such. I need to put together a page which shows a series of groups and within each group shows several images and each image can be clicked on to bring up a lightbox for browsing through each of the photos. For example, let's say the page is a photo gallery of a vacation, it might be something like:

Day 0

---

Photo thumbnail of a building, click on it and you see all my architectural photos from Day 0

Photo thumbnail of my dog, click on it and you see all my dog photos from Day 0

Day 1

---

Photo thumbnail of a building, click on it and you see all my architectural photos from Day 1

Photo thumbnail of food, click on it and you see all my food photos from Day 1

Photo thumbnail of my sister, click on it and you see all my family photos from Day 1

---

Etc. I've installed and played with [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) and [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) and managed to get a very simple type of gallery, but I'm wondering if there is a groupable gallery plugin out there or if I'll need to roll my own.

It is my assumption, and PLEASE correct me if I'm thinking wrongly with drupal here, that I'll need to create a content type for my gallery node, add fields to it for images (but I really feel like I need a grouped images data type because there won't be a fixed number of groups or a fixed number of galleries within each group), and then I need some kind of formatter plugin which will take the list of images and generate the html/javascript necessary to present that data (model) on the page (view).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a content type called Gallery with no extra fields
2. Create a content type called Image with a multi-upload image field and then a node reference field.
3. Create a view that brings in all of the gallery node types and then another display as an Entity Attachment in that same view that brings in all of the images.

Modules needed:

- http://drupal.org/project/plup
- http://drupal.org/project/references
- http://drupal.org/project/views
- http://drupal.org/project/eva
- http://drupal.org/project/entity

Example of the views setup:

[image: Views Photo Gallery Page Setup]
[image: Views Photo Gallery Entity Attachment Setup]

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just to expand a little: references lets you reference or point to other nodes of a specific content type from your current content type.

So, you could make one content type that is your 'Gallery' and just add a field there for your thumbnail image (or any other field that's relevant to the GROUP).

Then, in your Image content type, add any tags or other fields you want, AND a reference to a gallery node. This way, when you create a new image, you'll be able to select which gallery you want it to belong to!

Comment: Thank you both for the in depth response! It makes sense and I'm working through it to get a working example. I still don't grok the Views module yet though. I'm in the middle of watching a tutorial video about the Views module, but if you have a moment to explain a few more details about how to do #3, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to GET to the place where you took the above screenshots. I'll finish with this tutorial and try to see if I can emulate the settings above and get this working. :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! This video tutorial (http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-tutorial) helped me get to the point where I understand what Views really are and how to use them. Coupled with your description above, I've got the data in place and being selected. Now I just need to figure out how to style it the way I want! :)

Comment: Very good.  Use image styles to bring in thumbnail sizes here is an example of a D6 photo gallery with styles at the bottom of the post http://3wavesmedia.com/blog/create-awesome-photo-gallery-drupal-6